# Can I use HTML Webpack Plugin with a django base template?

Tags: webpack

I am learning **Webpack 2**, and I'm trying to integrate it with a **Django** project. 
there is a plugin for webpack, the *HTML Webpack Plugin*, this plugin can take a **template** and use it to generate another html file containing the style and script tags injected because the name of the js and css bundles contain a **[hash]** generated by another plugin.
the question is, can I use my Django's **base.html** file as the template file for the html Webpack plugin?. base.html contain template tags and Django DTL specific code.
and if not. how can I automate the injection of the bundle files without me doing that manually. which is a lot of work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do this with [custom templates](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/README.md#writing-your-own-templates) for the plugin.

Comment: I used the webpack-bundle-tracker plugin and used a django app django-webpack-loader that provide a custom template like you mentioned.